# When I close my laptop, the screen won't turn back on. 23.04

Tags: 23.04

When I suspend, it's fine,but if I close the lid, whether or not I suspended it first, the screen remains completely blank, and I have to do a hard restart. This problem started yesterday, after a software update. I'm on an ASUS TUF F15.